# Cordova: Access photos in the CameraRoll without using an imagepicker

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-3

The [Cordova Camera API v3.1.0](http://docs.appgyver.com/en/edge/cordova_camera_camera.md.html#Camera) gives me access to a **single** CameraRoll photo through something like the [UIImagePicker](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html). But I need to be able to iterate through **every** photo in the CameraRoll to extract things like timestamp and GPS coordinates.

Will a custom Cordova plugin be able to provide complete access to CameraRoll photos through [ALAssetsLibrary](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/Reference/Reference.html) (iOS) **without** requiring me to copy every photo into App storage? (I assume there would be an equivalent native lib for Android.)

Also, if I write a custom plugin, will I also have to create a custom ImagePicker/Thumbnail Gallery to support user interactions? If so, could that be HTML5 or would it also be native?